# centering the page doesnt work with body selector but does with div page wrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a html site that I am developing:
the html code is like this:

HTML:

```
 <body>
--Rest of code-- 
</body>
```

css:

```
    body{
    width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
```

This doesn't work.The page does not center. However when I use this:

```
    <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
    --Rest of code--
    </div>
    </body>
```

and CSS:

```
.page-wrap{
width: 70%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

This works perfectly.

I cannot understand conceptually why does selecting body in css does not work. After all the content under body and the content under the div tag is the same isn't it?

Also with CSS, on the same lines I have a code like this

```
<div class="A">
<div class"container">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
```

In CSS if I want to style the "hello" I have to use

```
.A .container
```

and only

```
.A
```

does not work even though essentially .A and .container wraps the same content.

Can anyone explain this concept?

Comment: try centering html as well as body, so `html { /*everything you have for body*/}` in your css

Comment: a `DIV` is a block element, `BODY` is not. Try `body { display: block; }`

Comment: `body {display:block}` doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try adding

```
html { width: 100%; }
```

This tells the body to which it is 70% in relation to..

Also, be sure your entire code is wrapped with the `<html>` tag.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byQwW/)

Comment: Could also be possible the full html code isn't valid and doesn't have <html> tags...

Comment: You mean the jsFiddle example isn't valid?

Comment: js fiddle's automatically outputs the tags. You don't have to insert them. In fact, it tells you that if you do insert them.

Comment: Please know, that every block-element automatically has a width of 100%, no it rather has a width auto and that results in an full-width of the parent element. Width 100% destroys that and e.g. in IE means 100% of the window.

Comment: Does your html have the proper structure? <html><body></body></html>

Comment: Yup, I validated it in w3 validator

Comment: @dwreck08: you have a colon at the end of your CSS. It has to be a semicolon ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually... both of your codes work! http://jsfiddle.net/x6JGs/1/

```
body{
    width:70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.A {
    color: red;
    background: silver;
}
```

Comment: Somehow this works in jsfiddle. Doesn't work in an actual browser (using the latest chrome )

Answer (score 0):

```
/* for block elements with position relative */
.position-relative {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: {some-width};
}

/* for block elements with position absolute */
.position-absolute {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: {some-width};
}
.parent-of-position-absolute {
    position: relative;
}
```

Please know, that every block-element automatically has a width of 100%, no it rather has a width `auto` and that results in an full-width of the parent element. Width 100% destroys that and e.g. in IE means 100% of the window.